# Replace every space in the beginning of the string

Tags: php, preg-replace

Using php preg_replace.

Tried:

```
$test = "      123";
$test = preg_replace("/^\s/","?",$test);
echo '|' . $test;
```

Outputs:

> |? 123

What I need:

> |???????123

Also tried another variants, but they all replace only FIRST space or ALL-IN-ONE...

---

**Spaces inside of the string or at the end of the string - should NOT be touched.**

Comment: you only need to remove ^ from regex, thats why you only get first.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic: what if the space found at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do this much easier without regular expressions, utilizing [`strspn`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php):

```
$whitespaceCount = strspn($test, " \t\r\n");
$test = str_repeat("?", $whitespaceCount).substr($test, $whitespaceCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$test = "      12 3  s";
$test = preg_replace_callback("/^([\s]*)([^\s]*)/","mycalback",$test);
echo '|' . $test;

function mycalback($matches){
 return str_replace (" ", "?", $matches[1]).$matches[2];
}

?>
```

output:

```
|??????12 3 s
```

Comment: This will replace only spaces and it will do it everywhere inside the input string, not only at the start.

Answer (score 0):

why you just dont try this:

```
echo '|' . preg_replace('/\s/','?','    123');
```

Comment: because it also replaces spaces inside the string, f.ex: "   123  456" will return "???123??456", but I need: "???123  456"

Answer (score 0):

Try this : remove `^` from pattern which checks for the beginning of the string, So what happens is it only replaces the space at the beginning (just one space)

```
$test = "      123";
$test = preg_replace("/\s/","?",$test);
echo '|' . $test;
```

Comment: But now it replaces all spaces, not just those at the beginning of the string.

Comment: If string is like `$test = "      12   3";`. What would be the output?

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = "      123";
$test = preg_replace("/^[ ]|[ ]/","?",$test);
echo '|' . $test;
```

Comment: That pattern also replaces spaces inside the string.